# Как найти все символы до скобок [img]?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Как найти все символы до скобок [img], Через `exec` или `match`?
так-же считать информацию между `[img]`.

Пример строки:

```
Сегодня теплая солнечная погода[img]http://i.imgur.com/E9talog.png[/img], но передают что  заврата  будет[img]http://i.imgur.com/E9talog2222.png[/img]дождь.[img]http://i.imgur.com/E9talog333.png[/img]
```

Ожидается что-то вроеде этого:

```
Сегодня теплая солнечная погода   http://i.imgur.com/E9talog.png

но передают что  заврата  будет   http://i.imgur.com/E9talog2222.png

дождь.   http://i.imgur.com/E9talog333.png
```

Comment: Что значит "до скобок"? Какой результат вы ожидаете получить для приведенной строки?

Comment: @Dmitriy Simushev Подкорректировал своё сообщение.

Comment: @Dmitriy Simushev Составил болеее детальнео описание.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самый простой вариант, из тех, что я вижу, выглядит вот так:

```
/(.*?)\[img\](.*?)\[\/img\]/g
```

Рабочий [пример](https://regex101.com/r/yG4uQ7/1) на Regex101.

Comment: Большое  спасибо Вам. А почему он самый простой? А  Какие еще есть вариант?

Comment: Регулярные выражения - очень мощный механизм. Каждую задачу можно решить более чем одним способом. Что касается других RegExp под вашу задачу, то сейчас мне в голову ничего не приходит =)